# Getting Cython to work with WinPython 3.3 64-bit

Tags: python, cython

First of all, I got this working, but I really have no idea why this is working. Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

According to [this link](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows), getting cython to work in 64Bit Python 3 is really easy. After installing cython (I used what was shipped with WinPython) and winsdk, all I need to do is to run:

```
set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
setenv /x64 /release
```

and then it's all set! However, once I close that session and open a new one, I need to re-run that two lines of command again. Interestingly, I realized doing the following will save this effort, and I do not need to run that two lines when starting my ipython qtconsole:

1) Open my WinPython Command Prompt;

2) Go to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin>` and run the above two lines to set environmnet;

3) This is key: open ipython in that session, use Cython once (for any code, I used hello world).

And then from that point, it's all set!

First of all, I don't know why that's working. Secondly, if I do that in the Windows SDK command prompt, or CMD command prompt, it wouldn't work.

Could anyone please give some insight? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you close this question with a success, now that there is a compiler toolchain provided with any recent winpython releases ?

Comment: Thanks Sheers... That's an old question that I almost forgot :)